# Rails order of blank element within array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Assuming the following array:

```
["Palm nova", "", "Palm trad", "Palm discard", nil, "Palm actual"]
```

the goal is to extract the first item of the list, that is not a blank `""` or `nil`

The rails where clause allows to order the results based on one or more attributes, in `asc` or  `desc` order.  But where does that place the blank item when using Postgresql as the database?

Are `""` and `nil` treated the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition empty strings are ordered by comparing them with the `<` and `>` operators, as stated in the docs:

> ... Ascending order puts smaller values first, where "smaller" is defined
> in terms of the < operator. Similarly, descending order is determined
> with the > operator

Are "" and nil treated the same?: No. Again, from the docs *"By default, null values sort as if larger than any non-null value"*, so if you sort by `DESC` your NULL values will be at the beginning, if using `ASC` they'll be at the end.

Basically you can do three things;

- Or to modify your query to omit NULL and/or empty strings when filtering them if possible,
- Or to manipulate the resulting array to filter out nil and/or empty strings,
- Or to add an ORDER BY clause to your query to make sure NULL and/or empty strings have always an identified order in the result.

Comment: I searched for this but must have missed it.  Can you kindly provide link to docs?

Comment: Sure, here https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/queries-order.html in "Sorting Rows".

Answer (score 1):

> the goal is to extract the first item of the list, that is not a blank "" or nil
> If you mean a database select you can exclude these via SQL:

```
.where("col IS NOT NULL AND col != ''").limit(1)
```

Ruby can also filter arrays in memory. `Array#detect` will filter and return the first match. Using the Rails `Object#present?` extension we can do the following:

```
["Palm nova", "", "Palm trad", "Palm discard", nil, "Palm actual"].detect(&:present?)
```

Comment: Ah! pertinent use of `present`which equivocates nil and `""`.